# WMI to get drive letter association with physical drive path, misses CDROMs

Tags: vba, vbscript, wmi

I'm running the following WMI script to get the associations between drive letters and physical drives on the system, but for some reason it omits CDROMs/DVD-ROMs. Can someone tell me how to get those as well?

```
ComputerName = "."
Set wmiServices = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!//" & ComputerName)
Set wmiDiskDrives = wmiServices.ExecQuery _
    ("SELECT DeviceID FROM Win32_DiskDrive")

For Each wmiDiskDrive In wmiDiskDrives
    strEscapedDeviceID = _
        Replace(wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID, "\", "\\", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
    Set wmiDiskPartitions = wmiServices.ExecQuery _
        ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=""" & _
            strEscapedDeviceID & """} WHERE " & _
                "AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition")

    For Each wmiDiskPartition In wmiDiskPartitions
        Set wmiLogicalDisks = wmiServices.ExecQuery _
            ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=""" & _
                wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID & """} WHERE " & _
                    "AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")

        For Each wmiLogicalDisk In wmiLogicalDisks
            WScript.Echo wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID & " = " & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: This code is to detect drive letter is associated with logical disk partitions - is this what you actually want?  It sounds like simpler code, such as [Enumerating Disk Drive Properties Using FSO](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/disk/drives/#EnumDiskDrive.htm) may do?

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. The current script (if you run it) produces correlations between drive letters and physical drive paths. Something like: "C:" = "\\.\PhysicalDrive0", but it doesn't produce the same for my CD drive, i.e. "D:" = "\\.\CDROM0". I want to know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering all of the comments thus far, here is a script that adds the capability to list CD-Rom drives.

```
ComputerName = "."

Set dictDrives = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set listDriveLetters = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Set wmiServices = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!//" & ComputerName)
Set wmiDiskDrives = wmiServices.ExecQuery _
    ("SELECT DeviceID FROM Win32_DiskDrive")

For Each wmiDiskDrive In wmiDiskDrives
    strEscapedDeviceID = Replace(wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID, "\", "\\", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
    Set wmiDiskPartitions = wmiServices.ExecQuery _
        ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=""" & _
            strEscapedDeviceID & """} WHERE " & _
                "AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition")

    For Each wmiDiskPartition In wmiDiskPartitions
        Set wmiLogicalDisks = wmiServices.ExecQuery _
            ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=""" & _
                wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID & """} WHERE " & _
                    "AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")

        For Each wmiLogicalDisk In wmiLogicalDisks
            listDriveLetters.Add wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID
            dictDrives.Add wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID, wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID
        Next
    Next
Next

Set wmiCDROMDrives = wmiServices.ExecQuery _
    ("Select DeviceID, Drive, MediaLoaded from Win32_CDROMDrive")

For Each wmiCDROMDrive in wmiCDROMDrives
    If wmiCDROMDrive.MediaLoaded Then          ' Only show drives with inserted media
        listDriveLetters.Add wmiCDROMDrive.Drive
        dictDrives.Add wmiCDROMDrive.Drive, wmiCDROMDrive.DeviceID
    End If
Next

listDriveLetters.Sort                          ' List the drives in alphabetical order

For Each strDriveLetter in listDriveLetters
    WScript.Echo strDriveLetter & " = " & dictDrives.Item(strDriveLetter)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very close now. Your script gives me the following instead of a physical path for the CDROM: D: = IDE\CDROMHL-DT-ST_DVD+-RW_GH50N__________________B103____\4&363F6EBE&0&0.1.0

Comment: @ahmdo so didn't you try my code below (at top_ which provided the same outputs for the cd-rom info, ie `wmiDiskDrive.drive & "=" & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID`? +1 btw Nilpo

Comment: @ahmd0 A physical path such as \\.\CDROM0 can only be found in the Win32_PhysicalMedia class's Tag property.  There are no other associated classes or properties to link this to.  You would need to enumerate the devices yourself.  For instance, you might use the Win32_SystemDevices class.  The first CD-ROM you encounter would be at mount point 0, the second at mount point 1, etc.  Could be filtered by their association with the Win32_CDROMDrive class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you wouldn need to use the `Win32_CDROMDrive` WMI class to access CD-ROM info. The code you have above is looking for physical drives in the `Win32_DiskDrive` class, it excludes CD_ROM

You could additional lines to get similar data - but not the same given CD-ROMs don't have the Partition characteristics that your current code does

```
ComputerName = "."
Set wmiServices = GetObject _
                  ("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!//" & ComputerName)
Set wmiDiskDrives = wmiServices.ExecQuery _
                    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_CDROMDrive")
For Each wmiDiskDrive In wmiDiskDrives
    MsgBox wmiDiskDrive.drive & "=" & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID
Next
```

Instead I think this different VBS *may* do what you want - the may part as I dont think the partition info is relevant to you.

**[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) version**

```
Dim objFSO
Dim colDrives
Dim strOut
Dim strArray

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives
strArray = Array("Unknown", "Removable", "Fixed", "Network", "CD-ROM", "RAM Disk")
On Error Resume Next
'File system errors for virtual drives
For Each objDrive In colDrives
    strOut = "Drive letter: " & objDrive.DriveLetter & vbNewLine
    strOut = strOut & ("Drive type: " & strArray(objDrive.DriveType) & vbNewLine)
    strOut = strOut & ("File system: " & objDrive.FileSystem & vbNewLine)
    strOut = strOut & ("Path: " & objDrive.Path)
    wscript.echo strOut
Next
On Error GoTo 0
```

**[vba](/questions/tagged/vba) version**

```
Sub Test()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim colDrives As Object
Dim strOut As String
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives
On Error Resume Next
'File system errors for virtual drives
For Each objDrive In colDrives
    strOut = "Drive letter: " & objDrive.DriveLetter & vbNewLine
    strOut = strOut & ("Drive type: " & Choose(objDrive.DriveType + 1, "Unknown", "Removable", "Fixed", "Network", "CD-ROM", "RAM Disk") & vbNewLine)
    strOut = strOut & ("File system: " & objDrive.FileSystem & vbNewLine)
    strOut = strOut & ("Path: " & objDrive.Path)
    MsgBox strOut
Next
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: This is correct.  The Win32_DiskDrive class does not include any optical drives.

Comment: @brettdj Thank you, but that's not exactly what I need. Again, the goal of this code is to produce associations between drive letters and physical paths to the drive. Stuff like: "C:" = "\\.\PhysicalDrive0", "D:" = "\\.\CDROM0", "E:" = "\\.\PhysicalDrive2"

Comment: @Nilpo Yes, from my own experimentation I learned that Win32_DiskDrive does not include optical drives, but Win32_PhysicalMedia does, and I can use Tag property instead of DeviceID, but the code stops producing any results in the ASSOCIATORS OF part, and unfortunately I don't know WMI that well to fix it any further... Any ideas on this front?

Comment: @ahmd0 The Win32_PhysicalMedia class's Tag propery does work, however, it returns something like "\\.\CDROM0" for a CD drive.  This naming convention doesn't appear anywhere else in the WMI repository so there aren't any assocations of this property instance.  You would need to add a separate logic set to work with CD-ROM drives.

Comment: @Nilpo I see. Any idea how to accomplish it for a CDROM?

Comment: @ahmd0 Yes.  Added as an answer.