# Get Disk Number From Current Location

Tags: vbscript

I have a script I am running on my USB. I need it to return the disk Number of the USB for later use in running a command. Please Can Someone help me tried googling but I cant find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the information from the [`Win32_DiskDrive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType = 'USB'"
For Each d In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  WScript.Echo d.Index
Next
```

If you have more than one USB disk connected you need to provide additional filtering criteria, of course.

If you want to get the disk number by drive letter take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9367753/1630171).

Comment: Good answer, not a great question.